# Sum of a list whose elements are themselves lists

Tags: python

Suppose i have a list;

```
list1 = [[1,2,3],[5,6,7], [7,8,9]]
```

When i execute the following line of code

```
for x in list1: sum(x)
```

I receive

```
6
18
24
```

I would like to sum all numbers in list1 using one comprehension and two sum() methods. That will also work if one of the list elements is a list of float objects.

Comment: `sum(map(sum, list1))`. also `sum(sum(list1, []))`

Comment: Definitely not Peter , i require something very different. Thanks though, for the extra info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
sum([sum(x) for x in list1])
```

Comment: You don't need the list comprehension but can use a generator expression: `sum(sum(x) for x in list1)`

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative answer you can sum all the inner list with [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) then calculate the `sum` :

```
>>> sum(reduce(lambda x,y :x+y,list1))
48
```